# How to recognize to whom to send a Push Notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

For example, I have on my app two options - `A` and `B`. I want to send my Push Notification to **users** who chose the `A`, **only**. How can I do it?

How can I separate my users and chose to whom to send my push notification, to the users who chose `A`, or to users who chose `B` option on settings of the app?

Can you please describe me this process or just provide me a plan. I'll do it for the first time, so it would be very useful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a server-side issue.

The apps must inform the server which type of notifications they want and the server saves this information. Then the server consults this information when sending notifications.

Comment: Can I configure Apple Push Notifications with my back-end or I need another tool?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use a 3rd party like UrbanAirship or Pubnub.

When they chose A or B, you register users to Channels/Segments and then when you want to send a push notification from Pubnub/Urbanairship, you select the segment/channel you want to send it to.

It's quite straightforward and very well documented with Pubnub. However, these services are often quite pricy.